# STRSPLIT and REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL in PigLatin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a following file:

```
File
----
12-3    John    121
 5-1    Sam     122
```

The file is tab(`\t`) delimited. I am loading the row as `line:chararray` as I want the data not to be split in individual fields.

And now, I want to pull and store the details (12-3, and 5-1) as separate data.

I am trying with `STRSPLIT` and `REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL`, but the data doesn't seem to match.

```
splitdata = FOREACH filedata {
    regex = REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line, '^([0-9]*)\\-([0-9]*)');
    split = STRSPLIT(line, '\\t', 1);
    GENERATE regex, split;
};
```

This is how I want my final data to be:

```
(12, 3, 12-3    John    121)
( 5, 1,  5-1    Sam     122)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks Lorand.

Since you gave a little idea about how to use the `REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL`, here is how I finally used it.

```
FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line, '^([0-9]*)\\-([0-9]*).*')) 
  AS (FIELD1:chararray, FIELD2:chararray), line;
```

Pretty interesting to know that Matcher.matches() fails for `'^([0-9]*)\\-([0-9]*)'` while works for `'^([0-9]*)\\-([0-9]*).*'`.

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
A = LOAD .... AS (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line, '^(.*)\t(.*)\t(.*)$')) 
      AS (id:chararray, name:chararray, nameid:chararray);
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(id, '^([0-9]*)\\-([0-9]*)')), 
      id, name, nameid;
STORE C INTO ...
```

If you would split the lines into fields along \t when loading, you could skip `B = ...`