# Split characters inside Pig field

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, udf

I have a text input with '|' separator as

```
0.0000|25000|                    |BM|BM901002500109999998|SZ
```

which I split using PigStorage

```
A = LOAD '/user/hue/data.txt' using PigStorage('|');
```

Now I need to split the field **BM901002500109999998**  into different fields based on their position , say 0-2 = BM - Field1 and like wise.
So after this step I should get BM, 90100, 2500, 10, 9999998.
Is there any way in Pig script to achieve this, otherwise I plan to write an UDF and put separator on required positions.

Thanks.

Comment: are you looking for substring ? http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/SUBSTRING.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `SUBSTRING`:

```
A = LOAD '/user/hue/data.txt' using PigStorage('|');
B = FOREACH A GENERATE SUBSTRING($4,0,2) AS FIELD_1, SUBSTRING($4,2,7) AS FIELD_2, SUBSTRING($4,7,11) AS FIELD_3, SUBSTRING($4,11,13) AS FIELD_4, SUBSTRING($4,13,20) AS FIELD_5;
```

The output would be:

```
dump B;
(BM,90100,2500,10,9999998)
```

You can find more info about this function [here.](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/SUBSTRING.html)

Answer (score 2):

I think that it will be much more efficient to use the built in UDF **REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL**.
You can get some idea of how to use this UDF from:

- http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/piglatin_ref2.html#REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL
- [STRSPLIT and REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL in PigLatin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396778/strsplit-and-regex-extract-all-in-piglatin)